# TSQL - Max per group?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a table that looks like this:

```
GroupID   UserID    Value
1         1         10
1         2         20
1         3         30
1         4         40
1         5         45
1         6         49
1         7         80
1         8         90
2         1          2
2         2         24
2         3         34
2         4         48
2         5         56
3         1         etc.
3         2
3         3
3         4
4         1
4         2
4         3
```

I am trying to write a LEAD function that will give me the midpoint between each value. To do this I have written the following:

```
SELECT 
  [GroupID]
, [UserID]+0.5
, (LEAD ([Value], 1) OVER (ORDER BY GroupID, UserID) + [Value])/2 as [Value] 
from dbo.myTable
```

The problem with this function is that when it gets to the last User in the group, it gives me a bad value because it's taking the [Value] on the current row and the value from the next row.

What I want to do is stop it when it reaches the maximum UserID for each Group. In other words, when it gets to `GroupID = 1` and `UserID = 8`, it should end and start at the next Group. I do not want a row that looks like this:

```
GroupID    UserID    Value
1          8.5       46
```

I could run a `DELETE` statement after I `INSERT` the rows into the original table, but I don't have anything to identify when a row is the "maximum" User for it's Group. Ideally, I would like to somehow tell the lead statement not to calculate it in the first place.

Comment: Does adding `PARTITION BY groupId` to your LEAD statement help get you closer? E.g. `(LEAD ([Value], 1) OVER (PARTITION BY GroupID ORDER BY GroupID, UserID)'

Comment: you can use case when groupid = lead(groupid,1) ...